# How do I make the view blurry like in IOS 8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

In Xcode 6, I'm making a game in Objective-C and when you lose I want the view to be blurred. Kind of like this, but a little less blurred: [image]

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add a UIBlurEffect in a UIVisualEffectsView. [Here](http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/a-primer-on-ios-8-visual-effects/159) is a good tutorial that might help you solve your problem.

I would recommend doing some research before asking, there are tons of tutorials out there and this question was asked several times before.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me:

> ```
> UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark];
> UIVisualEffectView *blurEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
> [blurEffectView setFrame:self.view.bounds];
> [self.view addSubview:blurEffectView];
> ```